# MathJax in Angular5 Component with Firebase Data

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, angular5, mathjax

I am trying to update data pulled from Firebase so that it displays equations on the page instead of random symbols signifying Latex syntax. I am able to include MathJax in my project through a script tag and then use it to correctly show a paragraph with math notation but I am not able to use it in other components across my project. Is there a better way to npm install dependencies I need and how do I get my Firebase data that is already correctly being pulled to the page to update using MathJax to have the correct format?

My index.html head tag is as follows:

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Testing</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.8.0/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>

  <script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
        MathJax.Hub.Config({tex2jax: {inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']]}})
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" async
          src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.2/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML">
  </script>

</head>
```

My component.html is as follows:

```js
<div class="topnav">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Search..">
<div class="theoremsContainer">
  <ul>
    <div *ngFor="let theorem of bibleObservable | async">
      <ngb-alert type="info" [dismissible]="false">
        <h1>{{theorem.rule}}: {{theorem.name}}</h1>
        <p>{{theorem.eq}}</p>
      </ngb-alert>
    </div>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

And my component.ts is as follows:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-bible',
  templateUrl: './bible.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./bible.component.scss']
})
export class BibleComponent implements OnInit {

  bibleObservable: Observable<any[]>;

  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.bibleObservable = this.getRule('/theorems');
  }

  getRule(listPath): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.db.list(listPath).valueChanges();
  }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not familiar with the MathJax library itself but it sounds like you need it to perform in the template so perhaps a custom directive?  https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives

Comment: How do I allow MathJax to talk with elements nested withing the ngFor loop div? I am able to make it work outside of the div. Does it have something to do with the face that I pulled the data down from Firebase?